# How to link to already compiled external shared libraries in RCPP using Makevars?

Tags: c++, rcpp

I have looked at multiple places but failed to find a simple example for my problem.

What I need is to be able to use multiple .so files which I have (together with .h files).

A simple example would be:

I have the following files: a.h, a.cpp the function jeden - this is my R library, accessor.cpp which exposes to R the function dwa from external library libdwa.so. I have the header file dwa.h and this library libdwa.so.

I can manage building binary package (and everything works fine) only and only then when I put the library file libdwa.so into the directory '/usr/lib' (I use Debian). But it is not partable solution.

Where I should put the library "dwa" files (dwa.h and libdwa.so) and what flags add in the Makevars file to get portable solution?

### SUMMARY ADDED

I summarize my results here. I believe some extremaly simple examples are useful at start.

1. 2 external libraries put inside *inst*:

   ```
   /inst/include/dwa.h
   /inst/include/trzy.h
   /inst/jeden/libdwa.so
   /inst/jeden/libtrzy.so
   ```
2. *configure* file */configure* has the form (test6 is a name of the package):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   rpath=$(${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript -e 'cat(file.path(.libPaths()[1], "test6", "jeden"))') #'
   sed -e"s|@rpath@|"${rpath}"|" src/Makevars.in > src/Makevars

   exit 0
   ```
3. The file */src/Makevars.in* has the form:

   ```
   CXX_STD = CXX11

   PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include/ -I.
   PKG_LIBS     = -ldwa -ltrzy -L../inst/jeden -Wl,-rpath,@rpath@
   ```
4. The */src/accessor.cpp* expose the libraries function to R:

   ```
   #include <Rcpp.h>
   #include "../inst/include/dwa.h"
   #include "../inst/include/trzy.h"

   // [[Rcpp::export]]
   Rcpp::String r_dwa() {
     Rcpp::String res = dwa();.
     return res;
   }

   // [[Rcpp::export]]
   Rcpp::String r_trzy() {
     Rcpp::String res = trzy();.
     return res;
   }
   ```
5. Pure R library _/src/hello_world.cpp_ also exists:

   ```
   #include <Rcpp.h>
   using namespace Rcpp;

   // [[Rcpp::export]]
   String hello_world() {
     String hw = "Hello World";
     return hw ;
   }
   ```
6. Finaly */NAMESPACE* file:

   ```
   useDynLib("test6", .registration=TRUE)

   import("Rcpp")
   importFrom("utils", "object.size", "packageVersion")
   exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
   ```

Building *source* and *binary* packages was successful but only *source* one is usefull as the *binary* has path to the libraries written rigidly.

Comment: In general, you cannot / should not and there are reason for that. We do it in the Rblpapi package because we have no other choice (only a shared library given) but we then control the path.  If you can get the sources and make it a _static_ library your life will be easier (if you plan to distribute your package).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am in just the same position as in the case of Rblpapi: got .so libraries that I have to expose to R.

Comment: As @Ralf showed you, you probably need the `rpath` option to tell the dynamic linker (which other has a path setting from the system) where to look. And for that you probably want to control the path as we do in Rblpapi.

Comment: You could have added that summary as an answer. Self-answers are ok! BTW, [staged install](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/02/14/staged-install/index.html) will make things like this more difficult, which is why Rblpapi has `StagedInstall: no` in `DESCRIPTION`.

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume you have a directory structure like

```
/opt/dwa/include/dwa.h
/opt/dwa/lib/libdwa.so
```

In that case you could use is `src/Makevars`:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I/opt/dwa/include
PKG_LIBS = -L/opt/dwa/lib -ldwa -Wl,-rpath,/opt/dwa/lib
```

Of course, this is still not portable, since the path to the library and header files is hard coded. To circumvent this, one uses a template file, e.g. `src/Makevars.in`

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = @DWA_INC@
PKG_LIBS = @DWA_LIB@
```

and writes a `configure` script that inspects the environment and creates `src/Makevars` based on the findings. There are different strategies for writing `configure` scripts. I typically use `autoconf`, e.g. in [RcppArrayFire](https://github.com/daqana/rcpparrayfire) or [dqmagic](https://github.com/daqana/dqmagic).

Comment: It's a good answer (that I upvoted) but there may be more as discussed above.

Comment: @Dirk It is indeed another level of complexity if the library is to be included in the R package.

Comment: Ralf, thank you for your comment. I was succeded in package building. Now it's time to the next step you and Dirk mentioned: ho to put the library into R package. Thank you again.

Comment: @Francisco: If it helped you should consider "accepting" the answer by clicking on the tick mark.

Comment: Dirk, thank you for the note. I've click the Ralf's triangle up, I believe it is it.

By the way, could you direct me somehow how to include the external libraries in R binary package and there wouldn't be problems with loading the libs?

Comment: @francisco Dirk will be notified about your message only when you add an at-sign. Anyway, you up-voted while he talked about accepting the answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for the difference. As for your question: Have you looked at how it is done in case of the Rblpapi package?

Comment: Yes, I have. One step further! But not full success. I have prepared for dwaapi Makevars.in and configure as in Rblpapi and building and installation is OK both as a root and a normal user (Debian) - independently. Thank you! However when I'd built binary package it can only be used by that user who have the same directories structer - I think because lib path to dwalib is rigidly written in the binary package. How to change the dependence during binary package installation?

Comment: @francisco Is the dwa library file part of the package (like for Rblpapi)? I don't know of any hooks that allow you to find external libraries when installing a *binary* package.

Comment: @Ralf, yes dwa is a part of the package. Meantime I've built _source_ package and it works great: each user can install it successfully.