# How can I load C++ modules and include compilation flags as a part of Rcpp package compilation?

Tags: c++, r, compilation, rcpp, htslib

I am using Rcpp to wrap a C++ program in an R package. My C++ program requires the following header:

```
#include "htslib/sam.h"
```

Prior to compilation, I typically load the following module in Ubuntu:

```
HTSlib/1.11-GCC-9.3.0
```

I typically compile the C++ script with the following flags in Ubuntu using GCC/9.3.0:

```
g++ scriptname.cpp -Ihtslib -Lhtslib -lhts
```

Since I am accessing the program from R via Rcpp, I do not know how to load the HTSlib module. When I attempt to "Clean and Rebuild" the package, I get the following error:

```
fatal error: htslib/sam.h: No such file or directory
    #include "htslib/sam.h"
                           ^
   compilation terminated.
```

I have two questions:

1. How do I load C++ modules when building an R package from C++ source code?
2. How do I include compilation flags when building an R package from C++ source code?

I have created a minimal header file, .R file, and C++ source script. The script opens a bam file and outputs the chromosome names and positions of the reads. These files do not represent the actual program I want to run (which is much too long and complicated to include here), but generate the same error when I attempt to build a package using Rcpp.

C++ source file:

```
#include "htslib/sam.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "HTSlibBasics.h

void OpenBam(std::string command_string){
    // Stores filename and converts to character string
    const char * char_command;
    char_command = command_string.c_str();
    
    // Opens bam file
    samFile *fp = sam_open(char_command, "r");
    
    // Opens bam header
    bam_hdr_t *h = sam_hdr_read(fp);
    
    // Initialize an alignment
    bam1_t *b = bam_init1();
    
    while(sam_read1(fp, h, b) >= 0) {
        if (b->core.tid < 0){
            continue;
        }else{
            std::cout << h->target_name[b->core.tid] << "\t" << b->core.pos << "\t" << bam_endpos(b) << std::endl;
       }
    }
    
    /*
    * Destroy the alignment and header which have been read into the C++ program
    * and close the sam file.
    */
    bam_destroy1(b);
    bam_hdr_destroy(h);
    sam_close(fp);
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef OPEN_BAM
#define OPEN_BAM

//' Documentation
//' @param command_string Documentation
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void OpenBam(std::string command_string);

#endif // OPEN_BAM
```

R file:

```
## usethis namespace: start
#' @useDynLib HTSlibBasics, .registration = TRUE
## usethis namespace: end
NULL
## usethis namespace: start
#' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp
## usethis namespace: end
NULL
#' Documentation
#' @export
OpenBam <- function(command_string) {
  .Call(`_HTSlibBasics_OpenBam`, command_string)
}
```

The R file goes in the "R" directory of the package while the C++ script and header go in the "src" directory.

Comment: It really is a bit more involved than just a quick answer here. I wrote [an entire vignette about that](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-libraries.pdf) which comes with your installed version of Rcpp, but which you can also get as a [paper at arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06416).

Comment: And feel free to swing by the rcpp-devel mailing list which is friendly.  Also, Bioconductor has a package interfacing htslib so you could look at that too.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into all of these sources

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: turns out the answer was pretty simple. I loosely followed Dirk Eddelbuettel's vignette (https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-libraries.pdf) and also combined a whole bunch of info from across the web.

In the command-line, I navigated to the HTSlib directory on my system:

```
cd /sw/eb/sw/HTSlib/1.11-GCC-9.3.0/
```

Next, I navigated to the directory with the htslib header files and moved them to the src/ directory for my R package:

```
cd include/htslib
cp *.h /home/annabelperry/R/HTSlibBasics/src/
```

Then, I navigated to my C++ source file and changed the header `include "htslib/sam.h"` to `include "sam.h"`, as my sam.h file was no longer in the htslib directory.

I then navigated to the HTSlib libraries directory and copied each of the files to a directory just outside my R package. (Note: I tried copying the whole directory and moving it, but this led to edit access issues).

```
cd /sw/eb/sw/HTSlib/1.11-GCC-9.3.0/lib
cp libhts.a /home/annabelperry/R/lib/
cp libhts.so /home/annabelperry/R/lib/
cp libhts.so.1.11 /home/annabelperry/R/lib/
cp libhts.so.3 /home/annabelperry/R/lib/
cd pkgconfig
cp htslib.pc /home/annabelperry/R/lib/pkgconfig/
```

I then created a file titled `Makevars` in the src/ directory for my R package and entered this:

```
CXX_STD = CXX11
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -Ihtslib
PKG_LIBS = -L/home/annabelperry/R/lib -lhts -Wl,-rpath,/home/annabelperry/R/lib
```

The `-L` linker flag gives the directory in which to find the library files and the `-l` linker flag gives the base name of the library files.

When I tried to build the package, I got an error saying the `libcrypto.so.10` library could not be found. I moved this library from its original directory, `/usr/lib64`, to the `/home/annabelperry/R/lib/` directory with the rest of my library files.

I also had to remove all `std::cout` calls from my source code, as they are incompatible with Rcpp.

After this, I could successfully build the package.

Comment: "Yes, but" copying the .lib and .a libraries includes binary artifacts in your package which would exclude it from CRAN or other repos were you try to upload it.

Comment: I didn't copy the library files into my package directory (/home/annabelperry/R/HTSlibBasics/), I just moved them to a file in the same drive as my package directory (/home/annabelperry/R/lib/). I plan to write a configure script (in line with Ralf Stubner's answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56881806/how-to-link-to-already-compiled-external-shared-libraries-in-rcpp-using-makevars) to correct for that fact that my library directory is currently hard-coded in. Will this work?

Comment: Yes, I too have several packages doing it via `configure` (often calling `pkg-config`). There are many examples, many packages doing that, and many answers here.  It is not the easiest, but it is solid.  And you can for example look at https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Rhtslib.html (which I am unfamiliar with, but it intersects with your issue here).